# Correct execution time of CUDA program

Tags: time, cuda

I wrote a small program with which you can get edges of a digital image (the well-known Canny detector). It is necessary to measure the exact time (in milliseconds) of the algorithm execution on the device (GPU) (including the stages of data transfer). I attach the working program code in C:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <opencv2/core/cuda.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


__device__ __host__
void FirstRun (void)
{
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    clock_t time;
    if (argc != 2) 
    {
        cout << "Wrong number of arguments!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    const char* filename = argv[1];
    Mat img = imread(filename, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if( !img.data )
    { 
        cout << " --(!) Error reading images \n" << endl;
        return -2; 
    }

    double low_tresh = 100.0;
    double high_tresh = 150.0;
    int apperture_size = 3;
    bool useL2gradient = false;

    int imageWidth = img.cols;  
    int imageHeight = img.rows; 
    cout << "Width of image: " << imageWidth  << endl;
    cout << "Height of image: " << imageHeight << endl;
    cout << endl;

    FirstRun();

    // Canny algorithm
    cuda::GpuMat d_img(img);
    cuda::GpuMat d_edges;

    time = clock();
    Ptr<cuda::CannyEdgeDetector> canny = cuda::createCannyEdgeDetector(low_tresh, high_tresh, apperture_size, useL2gradient);
    canny->detect(d_img, d_edges);
    time = clock() - time;
    cout << "CannyCUDA time (ms): " << (float)time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get two different work times (image 7741 x 8862)

[image]

[image]

System configuration:

1) CPU: Intel Core i7 9600K (3.6 GHz), 32 GB RAM;

2) GPU: Nvidia Geforce RTX 2080 Ti;

3) OpenCV ver. 4.0

What time is right and do I measure it correctly, thank you!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/

Comment: And what time is right?

Comment: Obviously not `clock()`, because as you undoubtedly read in the link I provided, `clock()` "... returns the *processor time* consumed by the program"

Comment: The profiler gives the best measurement of kernel execution time on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different times you can measure when dealing with cuda.

Here are some solution you might want to try:

1. Measure the total time used by cuda: Use time() to get an absolute time value before using any cuda functions and time() again after you got the result. The difference will be the real time that passed.
2. Measure only the time of the calculation: cuda has some start-up overhead, but if you're not interested in that, because you will be using your code many times without exiting the cuda environment, you can measure it seperatly. Please read [the CUDA C Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf), it will explain the use of Events to be used for timing.
3. Use the profiler to get detailed information on what part of the program takes what part of time: The kernel times are expecially interesting, as they tell you how long your computations take. Be careful when looking at the API times. In your example, a lot of time is used by cudaEventCreate() as this is the first cuda function in your program, so it includes the start-up overhead. Also, cuda[...]Synchronize() doesnt actually take that long to be called, but it includes the time it is waiting for synchronization.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I noticed that a lot of time is also used by cudaCreateTextureObject(), but it is not clear, why. I think that is why the time in the pictures is different.

Comment: I haven't used that feature yet, but I guess it's probably just an expensive feature